# "Fechar" DLL aberta

Tags: c#

Eu criei uma dll para executar em runtime uma classe:

```
var classe = 
    "using System; " +
    "public static class CSharp" +
    "{" +
        "public static double Executar()" +
        "{" +
            "return 0;" +
        "}" +
    "}";
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("CSharp")
.WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
.AddReferences(
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location))
.AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(classe));

var fileName = "CSharp.dll";

compilation.Emit(fileName);

var carregarDll = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(Path.GetFullPath(fileName));
```

Quando executo a primeira vez, funciona, da segunda em diante da erro dizendo que o arquivo já esta em uso...

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file
>   'C:...\CSharp.dll' because it is being used by another process.'

Eu tentei algumas formas tipo com o `stream.Close()`, mas não funcionou, eu nunca usei uma dll e tal, então não sei nem o que tentar ou pesquisar para encontrar...

---

**UPDATE 1**

Eu estou dando uma olhada no [CSharpCompilation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilation?view=roslyn-dotnet), o Emit() tem um cancellationToken, mas não sei como usa-lo, vou continuar pesquisando...

Comment: Você realmente tem que jogar esse código dinâmico dentro do contexto da aplicação principal? Você não pode criar um domínio dentro do aplicativo que possa hospedar essa(s) classe(s) dinâmica(s)? Referência [`AppDomain`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Nunca utlizei AppDomain... Entao nao via isso como uma possibilidade... Dei uma pesquisada aqui, seria mais ou menos [isso](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42312/Loading-Assemblies-in-Separate-Directories-Into-a)?

Comment: Nao vou so simplesmente copiar e colar, mas sim entender o q esta fazendo, por isso quero saber se seria certo seguir pelo link que mandei

Comment: Eu não analisei a fundo o link que mandou, pois estou trabalhando, mas por cima é bem próximo do que sugeri(provavelmente exatamente minha sugestão). Se o uso do `AppDomain` for na direção do que procura, a noite eu posso dar um exemplo de como compilar, recompilar e descartar o código compilado junto do domínio.

Comment: Puts @AugustoVasques, ia me ajudar muito, agradeço se puder me mostra sim...

Comment: Fui escrever o exemplo e tenho duas péssimas noticias. 1: O NET Core 3 não suporta múltiplos domínios. 2: O método [AssemblyLoadContext.Unload](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.unload?view=netcore-3.0) só existe na documentação. Por enquanto a única forma desse código progredir é em .NET 4

Comment: Eu estou utilizando o .net 2.2

Comment: Mas o 'Unload' é so .net 3 ne...

Comment: Me expressei mal. Core .NET é uma coisa e .NET Framework é outra. Esse código que escreveu é para Core .NET esse código só vai progredir em .NET Framework.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101683/discussion-between-leohenrique-and-augusto-vasques).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei um projeto .NET Core 3.0 e resolvi meu problema utilizando o [AssemblyLoadContext.Unload](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.unload?view=netcore-3.0) que foi sugerido pelo [Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques):

Fiz de 2 formas:

1: InMemory:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private static void ExecuteInMemoryAssembly(Compilation compilation, int i)
{
    var context = new CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext();

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var cr = compilation.Emit(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var assembly = context.LoadFromStream(ms);

        var type = assembly.GetType("CSharp");
        var greetMethod = type.GetMethod("Executar");

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var result = greetMethod.Invoke(instance, null);
    }
    context.Unload();
}
```

2: Com a Dll

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private static void ExecuteAssembly(int i, string path)
{
    var context = new CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext();
    var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path);

    using (var fs = new FileStream(assemblyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var assembly = context.LoadFromStream(fs);

        var type = assembly.GetType("CSharp");
        var method = type.GetMethod("Executar");

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var result = method.Invoke(instance,null);
    }

    context.Unload();
}
```

CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext:

```
public class CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext 
{
    public CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext() : base(isCollectible: true)
    { }

    protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
private static Assembly SystemRuntime = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Runtime"));

[HttpGet]
public void Get()
{
    var fileName = "CSharp.dll";
    var classe = "public class CSharp \r\n" +
       "\t{\r\n" +
       "\t\t public double Executar()\r\n" +
       "\t\t{\r\n" +
       "\t\t\t return 26; \r\n" +
       "\t\t}\r\n" +
       "}";
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("DynamicAssembly", new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(classe) }, new[] {
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Console).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(SystemRuntime.Location),
   }, new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

    for (var i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        ExecuteInMemoryAssembly(compilation, i); // (1)
        ExecuteAssembly(i, Path.GetFullPath(fileName));  //  (2)
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

REFERENCIAS:

https://www.strathweb.com/2019/01/collectible-assemblies-in-net-core-3-0/

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability