# Erro ao fazer POST em outro projeto pela segunda vez

Tags: c#

Pegando como base este [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/424439/104028), que foi eu mesmo quem postei, vou resumir para que entenda rapidamente...

Eu tenho um projeto .NET Core 2.2 e precisava de uma funcionalidade que só tinha no .NET Core 3.0, portanto criei um projeto em .NET Core 3.0 e estou fazendo um request via POST que retorna uma string que pode ser um valor ou uma mensagem de erro...

1. O erro que da:

[image: erro]

2. Quando ocorre:

Ocorre quando faz o segundo request, ou seja, quando o projeto .Net Core 2.2 chama o 3.0 pela segunda vez, ao executar o metodo `ExecuteInMemoryAssembly`, está mensagem aparece na linha que contem este codigo: `var cr = compilation.Emit(ms);`

> IMPORTANTE: Se eu parar o projeto e executar de novo, repete a situação, portanto, a primeira vez funciona corretamente e na segunda ele da o erro. (Na realidade ele crasha, então automaticamente o projeto para).

Procurei [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/seccrypto/common-hresult-values?redirectedfrom=MSDN), mas continuo sem saber como resolver:

> E_INVALIDARG: One or more arguments are not valid

---

UPDATE 1:

```
private static void ExecuteInMemoryAssembly(Compilation compilation)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}    

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposed)
        return;
    if (disposing)
    {
        handle.Dispose();
    }
    disposed = true;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou apagar os arquivos da pasta temporária de seu PC ?C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\"versao"\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ Cara sou meio leigo, mas já ouvi sobre isso.

Comment: Ola @AndreySchemel, eu fiz o que indicou, a pasta estava vazia... Talvez seja porque estou utilizando o .NET Core... Sabe tem temp para o core também? Tambem sou leigo, pode ser que esteja falando besteira

Comment: Creio que era pra ser mais ou menos esse caminho, estou sem .NET aqui, se não for esse deve estar em pastas mais "acima". Outra coisa que me veio a cabeça, é o método dispose, que libera recursos quando a classe não é mais utilizada (pode ser que seja besteira de novo).

Comment: Vou colocar um update com o Dispose, tambem nao funcionou